# C# Class Instance Size in memory

Tags: c#, memory, memory-management

I've the following scenario:

```
public class Test
{
    public void main()
    {
        //arrange
        var a = new A(4,2);
        var b = new B(3, 6, 6, 4);

        //act
        var a1 = a.ObjectToByteArray();
        var b1 = b.ObjectToByteArray();

    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1, Size = 3)]
    public class A
    {
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U1, SizeConst = 1)]
        byte a1;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U1, SizeConst = 1)]
        byte a2;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U1, SizeConst = 1)]
        byte a3;

        public A(byte a1, byte a2)
        {
            this.a1 = a1;
            this.a2 = a2;
            this.a3 = 9;
        }
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1, Size = 6)]
    public class B : A
    {
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U1, SizeConst = 1)]
        byte b1;

        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U1, SizeConst = 1)]
        byte b2;

        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U1, SizeConst = 1)]
        byte b3;

        public B(byte a1, byte a2, byte b1, byte b2) : base(a1, a2)
        {
            this.b1 = b1;
            this.b2 = b2;
            this.b3 = 8;
        }
    }
}
```

And then the extension method:

```
public static byte[] ObjectToByteArray<T>(this T source)
    {
        int rawSize = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(T));
        var rawData = new byte[rawSize];

        //var h1 = GCHandle.Alloc(source, GCHandleType.Pinned);
        //var ptr = h1.AddrOfPinnedObject();
        //h1.Free();

        var handle = GCHandle.Alloc(rawData, GCHandleType.Pinned);
        Marshal.StructureToPtr(source, handle.AddrOfPinnedObject(), false);

        handle.Free();

        return rawData;

    }
```

The first instance of the A type (a) size is determined by the  `Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(T))` function is right (3 bytes), but when in cames to the second instance of B type (b), the same function returns 7 instead of 6 bytes.
Can anyone explain what I'm doing wrong, or this is an expected behavior?

Thanks in advance,
Julian

Comment: On my machine, this gives the expected result (on a 64-bit runtime) by leaving out the `Size` altogether. It appears the marshaller does not take inheritance into account when evaluating the `Size`. You should leave it out in any case unless your intent is to pad the result, as ithe marshaller ignores this attribute if you attempt to make the size less than the minimum. Also, none of the `MarshalAs` attributes are necessary, since you're just spelling out the default marshalling for bytes (and `SizeConst` is ignored, as it's relevant only for arrays). Don't overspecify things.

Comment: Also, it's important to note that what you're specifying here is the way to *marshal* the class. This is *not* the size of the classes in (managed) memory, which ignores all this packing and layout business. Marshalling is not necessarily the most convenient way to just get a particular sequence of bytes to appear; it should only be used to interop with unmanaged code.

Comment: @JeroenMostert all you suggested is right, it worked, leaving `MarshalAs` attribute. Just one clarification: if there are array members in the class, they should be with the `MarshalAs` attribute? Has I understood right?

Comment: If you specify no `MarshalAs`, the array member is marshaled as a pointer, which is probably not what you want. To marshal the array as an embedded sequence of values, you have to use `MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = ...)`. In this case, the size must be constant, as the default marshaling can't handle anything more complicated.